# Solving STOMP Error "There is no current subscription with tag 'T-...''' in RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, subscription, stomp, subscribe

I'm facing the error message 'There is no current subscription with tag `'T_1'`. Due to this error, my connections are terminated which decreases the performance of my system.
First of, the environment I'm running:

1. Client app (Created in c#)
2. Server app (Created with spring boot version 2.6.0)
3. RabbitMQ (3.9.11) as message broker. Using STOMP plugin.

These 3 services works great in general. I'm not having any issues with these besides the error message described above (There is no current subscription with tag `'T_1'`). Please also note that the tag can be any subscription ID, not neccesairy `T_1`, but also e.g `T_100`

**When does the error occur:**
I've noticed that the error usually occurs during a particular state of my program. In this state, the C# client app should subscribe to a topic named 'xxx.pong'. Empty messages are frequently sent to this topic by other client applications. Once retrieved a pong message, the C# client app should unsubscribe to this topic.

**How I replicated the issue:**
I created a test case similar to the description above. I've added the code as an attachment. The error occurs around 1 out of 10 test runs and it's the consumer (which subscribes and unsubscribes) that retrieves the error message. The publisher (which frequently sends pong messages) does not retrieve errors.

**Logs when the error occurs:**

**Spring boot log:**

```
2022-01-06 14:04:12.165 ERROR 25116 --- [ent-scheduler-7] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Received ERROR {message=[Subscription not found], content-type=[text/plain], version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[48]} session=0009197b-1281-0fdb-08fe-3f5de331fdb9, user=XXX) text/plain payload=There is no current subscription with tag 'T_1'.
```

**RabbitMQ log (Note that the RabbitMQ serves timezone is 1 hour behind my local PC zone):**

```
2022-01-06 13:04:06.450156+00:00 [info] <0.9710.0> Supervisor {<0.9710.0>,rabbit_connection_helper_sup}: child heartbeat_sender started (<0.9728.0>): {rabbit_heartbeat,start_heartbeat_sender,[#Port<0.1398>,10,#Fun<rabbit_stomp_reader.1.31184097>,{heartbeat_sender,unknown}]}
2022-01-06 13:04:06.450237+00:00 [info] <0.9710.0> Supervisor {<0.9710.0>,rabbit_connection_helper_sup}: child heartbeat_receiver started (<0.9729.0>): {rabbit_heartbeat,start_heartbeat_receiver,[#Port<0.1398>,55,#Fun<rabbit_stomp_reader.2.31184097>,{heartbeat_receiver,unknown}]}
2022-01-06 13:04:11.359597+00:00 [info] <0.9733.0> Supervisor {<0.9733.0>,rabbit_amqqueue_sup}: child rabbit_amqqueue started (<0.9734.0>): {rabbit_prequeue,start_link,[{amqqueue,{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"stomp-subscription-gItDy9sxnW3_TUCGLOs8PQ">>},false,true,none,[],none,[],[],[],undefined,undefined,[],[],live,0,[],<<"/">>,#{user => <<"guest">>},rabbit_classic_queue,#{}},declare,<0.9732.0>]}
2022-01-06 13:04:11.403234+00:00 [dbug] <0.9734.0> Deleting auto-delete queue 'stomp-subscription-gItDy9sxnW3_TUCGLOs8PQ' in vhost '/' because its last consumer with tag 'T_1' was cancelled
2022-01-06 13:04:11.412333+00:00 [info] <0.9687.0> closing STOMP connection <0.9687.0> (172.17.0.1:57136 -> 172.17.0.2:61613)
2022-01-06 13:04:11.412428+00:00 [dbug] <0.9741.0> Closing all channels from connection '172.17.0.1:57136 -> 172.17.0.2:61613' because it has been closed
```

This is the test which sometimes invokes the error:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyProject.Rabbitmq
{
    [TestClass]
    public class RabbitMqTests
    {
        private int _pongCounter;
        private int _pingCounter;
        private bool shouldStop = false;

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestTags()
        {
            var internalWs = new InternalWebsocket("Consumer");
            internalWs.Open();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            List<StompSubscription> subscriptions = new List<StompSubscription>();

            var task = new Task(() => SpamPong(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            task.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            var sub = internalWs.Subscribe(
                "xxx.pong",
                OnPongMessage, true);

            while (_pongCounter == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

            internalWs.Unsubscribe(sub);

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

        private void SpamPong()
        {
            var internalWs = new InternalWebsocket("producer");
            internalWs.Open();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);


            while (!shouldStop)
            {
                try
                {
                    internalWs.Send(new object(), "xxx.pong");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Log.Info("Has failed to send message");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }


        public virtual void OnPongMessage(object sender, InternalMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _pongCounter);
        }

        public virtual void OnPingMessage(object sender, InternalMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _pingCounter);
        }
    }
```